# Get long access token from instagram mobile app

Tags: authentication, instagram, instagram-graph-api

I'm using `

*[https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={{](https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=%7B%7B) instagramAppId }}&redirect_uri={{ redirectUrl }}&scope=user_media,user_profile&response_type=code*

` url to verify user via instagram api.

Is it possible to get access token from instagram mobile app? The web view with insta login needs credentials to login, even though user is logged in mobile app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webviews keep their own cookie jars, so you have to log in separately. You can't use the mobile app's tokens. You can open the login page in a browser instead of a web view. Then, if the user is already logged in to Instagram in this given browser, you will instantly get a response from the authorization endpoint. Still, the user needs to be logged in in the concrete browser, being logged in in the app won't help.

Comment: Does that issues describes what was you saying?
https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/611979854479878/?post_id=611979857813211